# Ajax actions get stuck after a few minutes of page inactivity

Tags: jsf, primefaces

If I load a JSF page and do not click anywhere for a few minutes and then try to execute any Ajax action, the page stucks and the Ajax status indicator keep spinning forever.

If I reload the page and try to execute the very same action, everything works great.

I'm using JSF with Primefaces and this behaviour reproduces on all my webapp's pages.

Comment: It sounds like your session is timing out. Whats your session timeout in minutes>

Comment: I've set the timeout to 1 minute for testing purposes. The weird thing is that while in the app's login page the session expires after 1 minute and the expected exception is thrown. However, after the user has logged in, the session no longer expires after 1 minute, and the above described behaviour is observed. I'm using Atmosphere's push feature (via Primefaces), so I think the session does not expire because Atmosphere keeps an open channel or something. However this does not explain the error described in the question.